# Plot shaded region around lines

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm looking for a way to plot a shaded region around each of the lines I calculate from a distribution of points (see attached image). The region should have a fixed width (10 pixels above and below the plotted lines). Things are a bit more complicated than usual because the code is written to consider a series of datasets, and for each set I need to plot several curves (the number changes from set to set). I tried various methods, including `errorbar(f(xx,:), threshold_distance_fit)`, with no success.

How do you suggest to solve the problem?

Here is the code I'm using to plot the dataset and the curves:

```
g = figure; xlabel('Omega'); ylabel('Y_detector');
plot(Angle, Y_measured, '*'); hold on;
f = zeros(number_centers, 180);
for xx = 1:number_centers
   for deg = 1:180
       % f is the fitting function
       f(xx, deg) = double((R_fit(xx)*sind(alpha_fit(xx)+deg)/0.05)+113);
   end
   plot(1:180, f(xx,:), '.'); hold on;
 end
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `patch`.

Comment: Sounds like a bad suggestion, but the best results you will get with post processing (assuming you save the plot as vector graphic) of the line with the desired linewidth. Using `patch` and optional the `FaceAlpha` property is an option, but be aware that the whole shaded region will be built of triangles. For multiple plots, there will be a huge number of triangles and displaying the figure gets really slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hesitating between using `patch` or `surface` and hbaderts was faster at proposing the `surface` option, so I'll show you how to do it with `patch`.

I'll give more construction detail in my example, but ultimately you can just replace my patches with surface objects if you prefer.

First I start to build series of curves looking like yours:

```
colorCollection = get(0,'defaultAxesColorOrder') ;
nPlot = 4 ;

h.fig  = figure ;
h.ax   = axes('NextPlot','add') ;

x = linspace(0,180) ;
f = zeros( nPlot , numel(x) ) ;
for k=1:nPlot
    f(k,:) = sin(k*x/180*pi) * 180 ;
    h.plotf(k) = plot( x , f(k,:) , '.' , 'Color',colorCollection(k,:) ) ;
end
```

This create and plot 4 curves. The next thing is to address your request of "*10 pixels above and 10 pixel below*". The plotted curves, or any patch/surface will have no notion of "pixel" but only of value in the data space. so you have to know how to convert pixel to data or the other way round.

```
%// retrieve a few propery values
xlim = get(h.ax,'XLim') ;               %// axes X limits
ylim = get(h.ax,'YLim') ;               %// axes Y limits
set( [h.ax h.fig] , 'Unit','Pixels')    %// set the axes units in pixel
axpos = get( h.ax,'Position') ;         %// get the coordinates of the axes object on the figure (in pixels)
nPix.W = round(axpos(3)) ;              %// axes WIDTH  , in [pixel]
nPix.H = round(axpos(4)) ;              %// axes HEIGHT , in [pixel]

%// calculate the vertical data/pixel ratio (to know how much "y" value
%// will correspond to "10" pixels)
nPixelOverlap = 10 ;                            %// this is defined in your question
pixelRatio  = (ylim(2)-ylim(1)) ./ nPix.H ;     %// =0.0052 in my example. => 1pixel=0.0052*y
dataOverlap = nPixelOverlap .* pixelRatio ;     %// how much I have to add or remove to a curve to cover 10 pixels
```

Once I have this magic coefficient `dataOverlap`, I can build graphic objects which will have to contain each curve, their higher and lower `Y` boundaries will be the value of the curve, with `dataOverlap` respectively added and subtracted.

In your case it seems you do not have large vectors (not so many `x` values), so part of the solution below may be overkill for your problem. But if you had to do the same thing with large data vectors (like thousands or worse, millions of elements), creating many patches (or even surfaces) with that many point would very likely almost freeze your figure (very slow response time, if not worse). An easy way round this is to plot a downsampled version. Since we already counted how many pixels the axes span, we can just create graphic objects just this size (so we have basically one `x` point per pixel, no more).

```
%// define a minimal "x" vector to populate every pixel in the axes
x4interp = linspace(xlim(1),xlim(2),nPix.W) ;

xpatch = [x4interp fliplr(x4interp)] ;          %// common X vector for all the patch objects
ypatch = zeros( nPlot , numel(xpatch) ) ;       %// preallocate Y arrays for each patch (one patch per initial curve)
for k=1:nPlot
    ytemp = interp1( x , f(k,:) , x4interp ) ;  %// reinterp the "k-th" curve value on the new "x" axis
    %// prepare the patch "Y" data (=the curve reinterpolated value + and - the overlap
    ypatch( k , : ) = [ytemp-dataOverlap fliplr(ytemp)+dataOverlap] ;
    %// plot the actual patch
    h.patch(k) = patch( xpatch , ypatch(k,:) , colorCollection(k,:) , 'FaceAlpha',0.2 , 'EdgeColor','none' ) ;
end
```

If you execute this example all in one go you should obtain something very similar (*The color might be different depending on which version of Matlab you are using*):

[image: multipatch]

As I said above, the last bit of reinterpolation is overkill for this example (the patches actually have *more* data points than the curves), but the good thing is that it is very scalable. You can use exactly the same method if your initial curves have 10<sup>7</sup> points, the patches are not going to hog your memory (*your curves may though*).

---

Note that the calculation of pixel/data ratio are depending on the size of your figure of the screen. If you resize the figure, the calculation are not updated. You either have to re-execute the calculation part and update the graphic objects, or the simplest is to set your figure to the desired size first, then execute the calculation and plot the graphic objects.

Answer (score 1):

A nice possibility would be to create the same plot with a larger linewidth and make it transparent. Unfortunately this is not easily possible in MATLAB, but there is some kind of workaround. You can create a [surface](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surface.html) plot with `z=0`, which will look exactly like a plot.

Note that if `x` and `y` are vectors of size `1 x n` and `1 x m` respectively, then `surface` assumes that `z` is a matrix of size `m x n`. Therefore you need to make `x`, `y` and `z` matrices. You can easily do that by `[x;x]` (assuming `x` is a row vector).

You can then specify the linewidth, the color and the opacity (alpha-value) for the surface plot.

E.g.

```
x = 0:0.01:2*pi;
y = sin(2*x);
z = zeros(size(x));

hold on;
surface([x;x],[y;y],[z;z], 'linew',20, 'edgecolor','r', 'edgealpha',0.2);
plot(x,y,'-r');
hold off;
```

creates:

[image: Example image sin(2*x)]